# xhgui doesn't save any data

Tags: php, mongodb, xhprof

I've installed all te prerequistes on an Ubuntu machine and added the following to my apache virtual host file

php_admin_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/xhgui/external/header.php"

After visiting the site I then go to /xhgui/webroot and just see the message

Looks like you haven't done any profiling

Mongodb is running but it seems as though no data is being saved there.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

external/header.php has logic to simply return; if rand(0, 100) does not return the value 42.  Try commenting that out (temporarily).

Comment: We've also changed the Readme to mention this specifically: https://github.com/preinheimer/xhgui/commit/a63174d857a72a464a325f9c2e745b9f78cd17b6

Answer (score 3):

I had a lot of problems installing xhgui.

First make sure mongo is correctly installed, and that you run php install.php without problems. Adding the extension mongodb fixed that for me:

extension=mongodb.so

instead of mongo.so

Also, make sure xhprof mongo db exists:

```
$ mongo
$ use xhprof
```

that's it, this commands will have created the collection for xhgui to use.

Once all that is done, put this lines in your vhost file (php.ini did not work for me):

php_admin_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/xhgui/external/header.php"

change header.php path to wherever is you header.php located.