# xhGUI only works inside /xhGUI

Tags: php, symfony, profiling

I made an install of xhGUI, that seems clean. Only problem, requests seems to be traced only in the xhgui file itself. I am on a production server, so there is supposed to be some requests.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJHhA.png (since I cannot post images..)

I have `auto_prepend_file = "/path/to/my/file/web/xhgui/external/header.php"` in php.ini.
I have not changed the xhGUI config file.

What im I doing wrong ?

Comment: is it the right line to put in php.ini ?  Or should I get rid of the `=` ?

I tried to place it in the httpd.conf instead whith `php_admin_value`, but it did not work. In the Readme it says that it could work by placing it in a .htaccess file, but isn't `php_admin_value` not allowed in these files ?

Comment: I am using Symfony2, is it possible that the requests does not use `php.ini` ? Or could it be an access problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575134/xhgui-doesnt-save-any-data?rq=1

Comment: @Niccor is correct; this line needs to go into the virtual host block. See here in this very good article :-

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-xhprof-and-xhgui-for-profiling-php-applications-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-6-%E2%80%94-set-up-xhprof